# update lambda function in code pipeline step

Tags: aws-cli, aws-codepipeline

I am building a docker image in an AWS code pipeline and pushing it to ECR. After pushing it, I'd like to update a lambda function to consume this newer version of the repo in ECR. My build yaml file looks like this:

```
 build:
                commands:
                  - echo Entered the post_build phase...
                  - echo Build completed on `date`
                  - docker build -t $imageName .
                  - docker tag $imageName $ecr:latest
                  - aws ecr get-login-password --region $region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $account.dkr.ecr.$region.amazonaws.com
                  - docker push $ecr
                  - echo going to update lambda 
                  - aws --version     
                  - echo $lambdaFunctionName
                  - echo $ecr
                  - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name  $function_name  --image-uri $ecr:latest
```

how can I update the AWS cli version used by my code pipeline and/or modify my `update-function-code` command to be compatible with AWS CLI 1.18

however the update lambda code command is failing with the following:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: --image-uri,
```

I believe this is because the code build pipeline is running an old version of the AWS CLI. I know this because I print out `aws --version` in the YAML file as well

```
aws-cli/1.18.49 Python/3.7.6 Linux/4.14.291-218.527.amzn2.x86_64 exec-env/AWS_ECS_EC2 botocore/1.15.49
```

update:

I downloaded AWS CLI version 1.18:

```
 curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle-1.18.49.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"\nunzip awscli-bundle.zip\nsudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

and when I look at the man page I see that image-uri is not supported:

```
NAME
       update-function-code -

DESCRIPTION
       Updates a Lambda function's code.

       The  function's  code  is  locked when you publish a version. You can't
       modify the code of a published version, only the unpublished version.

       See also: AWS API Documentation

       See 'aws help' for descriptions of global parameters.

SYNOPSIS
            update-function-code
          --function-name <value>
          [--zip-file <value>]
          [--s3-bucket <value>]
          [--s3-key <value>]
          [--s3-object-version <value>]
          [--publish | --no-publish]
          [--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
          [--revision-id <value>]
          [--cli-input-json <value>]
          [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

so I either need to update my pipeline to deploy the bundled resources to S3 and then update the lambda function or figure out a way to update the CLI version used by my pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I learned its possible to specify the image your build env uses. You can specify this manually in your build stage from within CodeBuild->Build->Build Projects->Edit->Environments.

When I opened this up I learned by my build is using  `“aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-aarch64-standard:1.0”`. You can specify a more recent version to use via "Override image"

In my CDK code I specified this override via

```
        const pipelineProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, `${props.lambdaFunctionName}-pipelineProject`, {
            ...etc... etc...
            environment: {
                buildImage: LinuxArmBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2_STANDARD_3_0
            }
        });
```

once I made this change I was able to confirm there was an updated CLI version `aws-cli/2.11.11 Python/3.11.2 Linux/4.14.311-233.529.amzn2.aarch64 exec-env/AWS_ECS_EC2 exe/aarch64.amzn.2023 prompt/off`